# Type 'URLSearchParams' is not assignable to type 'URLSearchParams'

Tags: angular, typescript, http, get

I want to send a http.get request with some search parameters to my webapi to get a list of students. I found some examples on how to do this, but after doing exactly as in the examples, I get this weird error:

```
Type 'URLSearchParams' is not assignable to type 'URLSearchParams'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
Property 'rawParams' is missing in type 'URLSearchParams'.
```

Here's my component:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { User } from '../_models/user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

options = new RequestOptions({ 'headers': new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })});

constructor(private http: Http) {
}

createAccount(newUser: User){
return this.http.post('http://localhost:64792/api/students', JSON.stringify(newUser), this.options)
.map((response: Response) => {              
    if(response.ok){
        console.log("Registration was a success");
        return true;
     } else {
         console.log("Registration failed");
         return false;
      }
 });
}

searchStudents(searchWords: Array<string>){
// Parameters obj-
 let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
 for(let i = 0; i < searchWords.length; i++){
 params.append('searchWords', searchWords[i]);
 }
 this.options.search = params;
 //Http request-
}
}
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use the [native URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). You should be using the [Angular one](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html) by importing it from `'@angular/http'`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It seems the native [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) is declared to your present code, whereas the `new URLSearchParams();` returns angular.io's [URLSearchParams object](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html)

import `'rxjs/add/operator/map'` and it should work.

```
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using set method

```
searchStudents(searchWords: Array<string>){
// Parameters obj-
 let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
 for(let i = 0; i < searchWords.length; i++){
 params.set('searchWords', searchWords[i]);
 }
 this.options.search = params;
 //Http request-
}
```